# Using crontab on a file in C

Tags: c, unix, cron

I have a file which includes crontab commands.I want to use crontab on that file in C.How can I accomplish this?My file is a normal C file which is defined as

```
File *file=fopen....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear but, you can call crontab with a file to set it up;

crontab [file]

What exactly do you mean by 'use crontab on'?

Comment: I exactly mean crontab[file].But I wrote a custom shell in C.Can I set it up in C with writing crontab[file]?.I know how to use it in terminal.I dont know how to code it in C

Comment: I think I figured out how to do it.I need to use exec v and give correct values to its args part.